# ModSecurity: How to write exclusion rules for list of REQUEST_URIs on separate domain names?

Tags: mod-security

I have a server with 100 domain names. On each domain name, I have a unique list of pages/directories that I would like to whitelist (put ModSecurity into DetectionOnly mode temporarily). Basically, how would I write the rule for something like this where there is a set of URLs for abc.com and a set of URLs on xyz.com?:

```
SecRule REQUEST_DOMAINNAME "abc.com" REQUEST_URI "@pm /account/bulk-upload.php /account/bulk-upload/ /account/edit-account.php /account/reply-or-delete.php /contact.php /contact/ /edit/ /edit-images/ /feedback/leave-feedback.php /feedback/feedback-reply.php /img/ /login.php /maintenance/ /register.php /sell/ /store/add-categories.php /store/edit-store.php" \
    "id:100002,\
    phase:1,\
    t:none,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleEngine=DetectionOnly"

SecRule REQUEST_DOMAINNAME "xyz.com" REQUEST_URI "@pm /account/bulk-upload.php /maintenance.php /edit/ /account/ /register.php /login.php /img/ /contact/ /contact-us.php" \
    "id:100003,\
    phase:1,\
    t:none,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    ctl:ruleEngine=DetectionOnly"
```

I am fairly inexperienced with ModSecurity rule writing, still learning. But is `@pm` the most efficient way to apply the same rule to a list of various PHP pages and full directories (which contain multiple PHP pages)? If not, what would be a better way to write this rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CRS Dev-On-Duty here. Unfortunately REQUEST_DOMAINNAME does not exist, but you can use `REQUEST_HEADERS:Host`. I think you'll have the information there.
Next problem we have to solve is that you can't add multiple variables to one rule. We have to `chain` them.

You can try if something like this works for you:

```
SecRule REQUEST_HEADERS:Host "@pm localhost xyz" \
    "id:10000,\
    phase:1,\
    pass,\
    nolog,\
    chain"
    SecRule REQUEST_URI "@pm /account/bulk-upload.php /account/bulk-upload/" \
       "ctl:ruleEngine=DetectionOnly"
```

Explanation:
First we check the `REQUEST_HEADERS:Host` against this list. And then we chain this rule with the rule that checks for your `REQUEST_URI` list.